# Can't build WPF VS2022 solution

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

My [Visual Studio 2022 solution](https://github.com/5cover/WinClean) won't build after I deleted the bin and obj folders of my C# WPF .NET 6.0 project.

The problem does not come from Visual Studio, as I've already tried reparing in Visual Studio Installer and I can build other WPF projects just fine.
The errors shown in the output window:

```
C:\Users\Scover\source\repos\WinClean\WinClean\Presentation\App.xaml(11,6): error MC3074: The tag 'GoldenRatioConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Scover.WinClean.Presentation.Converters'. Line 11 Position 6.

C:\Users\Scover\source\repos\WinClean\WinClean\Presentation\Controls\ScriptEditor.xaml(15,10): error MC3074: The tag 'IsNotNullConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Scover.WinClean.Presentation.Converters'. Line 15 Position 10.

C:\Users\Scover\source\repos\WinClean\WinClean\Presentation\Windows\AboutWindow.xaml(7,9): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'AppInfo'. Note that type names are case sensitive.

C:\Users\Scover\source\repos\WinClean\WinClean\Presentation\Windows\MainWindow.xaml(8,76): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'AppInfo'. Note that type names are case sensitive.

C:\Users\Scover\source\repos\WinClean\WinClean\Presentation\Windows\SettingsWindow.xaml(8,62): error MC3050: Cannot find the type 'SettingsWindow'. Note that type names are case sensitive.
```

The problem doesn't come from junk files in the solution folder either, as I've already tried starting fresh by cloning my repository

Comment: Does your `SettingsWindow.xaml.cs` class exist?  Is the class partially declared there?  Do its properties show the build action to be "C# Compiler".  I'm not downloading code from a github project to answer a question here but these are some fairly fundamental errors

Comment: Have you tried in other VS? Is problem persists then it’s not VS issue something else

Comment: @Joe yes it does, yes it's partial

Comment: @viveknuna I have the same errors in Blend for Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
I just removed this line from my `.csproj`

```
<AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
```

Comment: Thank for your sharing, Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to ch